# Steigerung von gefährdet

Tags: adjective

Wie ich gerade bemerke, fasst www.duden.de "gefährdet" offenbar als (echtes) Adjektiv auf, nicht nur als Partizip. Demnach müsste es auch "normal" gesteigert werden (so sieht das auch dict.cc; aber die steigern auch "besucht" herkömmlich - und bei einem Satz wie "Internationale Rockkonzerte zählen zu den besuchtesten Veranstaltungen" wird mir gelinde gesagt schlecht). Dennoch frage ich nach dieser Entdeckung, was besser ist:

1. Die Bundeskanzlerin zählt zu den gefährdetsten Personen
2. Die Bundeskanzlerin zählt zu den meistgefährdeten Personen

Comment: **gefährdetsten**

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Actually "gefähdet **e** sten" was copy-pasted from dict.cc; I told you I don't trust them so much :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an has always been: **gefährdetste(n)**.

[Here's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=meistgef%C3%A4hrdete,%20gef%C3%A4hrdetste&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,meistgef%C3%A4hrdete;,c0;.t1;,gef%C3%A4hrdetste;,c0) the Google n-gram for it.

Comment: Aber: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=meistgef%C3%A4hrdete%2Cgef%C3%A4hrdetste%2Cam+meisten+gef%C3%A4hrdete&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmeistgef%C3%A4hrdete%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgef%C3%A4hrdetste%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cam%20meisten%20gef%C3%A4hrdete%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2):

Das Folgende ist nur mein Sprachgefühl, das ich nicht weiter untermauern kann:

Wenn ein Partizip mit dem Präfix *meist* versehen wird, bedeutet dies für mich die höchste **Zahl** von Anwendungen des jeweiligen Verbs. Zum Beispiel wird der *meistgehasste Politiker* von der höheren Zahl von Menschen gehasst, was aber nicht heißen braucht, dass er die größte Gesamtmenge an Hass auf sich vereint – dies tut der *am stärksten gehasste Politiker¹.*

Da es in der Beispielaussage vermutlich nicht um die Anzahl der Gefahrenquellen, sondern aufsummierte Gefahrenstärke geht, würde ich Variante 2 nicht verwenden.

---

Eine Alternative zu Variante 1 ist übrigens noch:

> Die Bundeskanzlerin zählt zu den am stärksten gefährdeten Personen.

---

¹ Mathematisch: Sei *M* die Menge der Menschen und *h*(*m,p*) ≥ 0 die Menge an Hass, die der Mensch *m* dem Politiker *p* entgegenbringt. Dann ist für den meistgehassten Politiker #{*m*∈*M* | *h*(*p,m*) > 0} maximal und für den am stärksten gehassten Politiker Σ*h*(*p,m*) (wobei die Summe über alle m∈M geht).